# How to open downgrade a file in python using an NFS mount

Tags: python, nfs, nfsclient

I am running some experiments against NFS and would like to open-downgrade a file in my NFS mount but I do not which python command should I use for that.

Answer (score 0):

If an open-owner has opened the same file multiple times with different access and deny values, closing one of the opens will result in invocation of open_downgrade on NFS server.

```
fd1 = open("/home/ubuntu/v4/foo", 'r')
fd2 = open("/home/ubuntu/v4/foo", 'w')
fd1.close()
```